# Why can't run start delayed job command when use crontab

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, shell, cron, delayed-job

```
#!/bin/bash
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

cd /var/www/project
if [ ! -f tmp/pids/delayed_job.pid ]; then
  echo "File not found!"
  pwd
  ./bin/delayed_job start

  echo "Run script successful!"
fi
```

In my code start normally is work but run with crontab not work.

any idea pls.

Comment: Tell us a bit more about what you're trying to do here.  What controls the presence of `tmp/pids/delayed_job.pid` and what does your `crontab` entry look like?

Comment: In this line  `tmp/pids/delayed_job.pid` I check delayed job is running true or false 

in crontab file

`* * * * * /var/www/project/delayed_job.sh >> /var/www/project/delayed_job.txt`

Comment: More about this question i want to auto start delayed job with crontab when delayed job disappear.

Comment: crontab can't execute this line `./bin/delayed_job start`

Comment: thank you @rnorris

I can solved it.

In shell script don't know ruby environment i use .rbenv 
then i add ruby $home path to shell script can fixed it.

Comment: You can type up your solution below and accept it as the answer.  It may be useful for someone else who comes along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It solved.

I'm use rbenv for ruby install and setup it in to .bash_profile. Yes environment work but i run ruby in crontab not work.

Solution: I copy some config in .bash_profile to my script see below

`#!/bin/sh`

`#below script from .bash_profile`

`PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
export PATH
export PATH=$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"`

`#end script from .bash_profile`

`RAILS_HOME="/var/www/{project}"
if [ ! -f $RAILS_HOME/tmp/pids/delayed_job.pid ]; then
    echo "Starting Delayed job"
    $RAILS_HOME/bin/delayed_job start
fi`

Comment: This solution hasn't worked for me, but it was helpful in giving a right direction that what could be potential problem, hence +1 vote to question and answer. I'm adding my solution below in case it can help others.

Answer (score 0):

I  had slightly different requirement, but similar. We always run 5 DJ threads typically all the time. But in many cases, what happens is, if all the 5 threads are working on some long running jobs(even lower priority jobs), then it block high priority jobs and creats long wait time, which is not acceptable to many of our customers. Hence, I did similar thing, and via crontab only. So encountered same problem as mentioned in the ticket. So adding my solution here.

1. Run a cronjob to detect, how many jobs with priority 0 waiting in the queue, if its more than a fix no. e.g. 2 or 5 or anything.
2. Then, start another thread automatically.

Here is solution that I have done.

1. I have created a shell script, that query DJ table using mysql command from shell script. The shell script return 0 if new DJ Thread to be launched, otherwise 1. Pay attention to my `&&` in crontab command.

   `#step.1 script`
   `#!/bin/bash`

   `MYSQL_PWD="XXXX"`

   `field=$(mysql -h<yourhost> -u <user> --password="$MYSQL_PWD" <dbname> -A -BNe 'USE dbname; select count(1) from delayed_jobs where priority=0 and locked_at is null;' )`

   `if [ $field -gt 2 ]; then` 
   `return 0`
   `else`
   `return 1`
   `fi`
   `exit;`
2. then added a crontab command itself of launch on DJ thread with ID 5(tough it can be anything)
   code for 1&2 are mentioned below.

   `#step 2 crontab entry`

   `*/5 * * * * sh /your/sh/file/path/in/step/1/delayed_jobs_count.sh && cd /your/dj/app/path && RAILS_ENV=production /your/bundle/exec/path/bundle exec bin/delayed_job start -i 5 >> /your/home/logs/path/dj-start-cron-t.log 2>&1`